# Middleware in ExpressJS app uses next() to call itself

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a basic ExpressJS server that's simply meant to log a connection's IP, and serve static we pages. What happens when I connect to it myself is that the middleware that logs the request's IP repeats itself multiple times. If I remove the call to `next()` this stops, but it also prevents the middleware governing the static pages from running.

The server's code is this:

```
var express = require('express');

    app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Received a connection from: ' + req.ip)
    next();
})

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = 55671;
app.listen(port, function() { 
    console.log('Listening on: ' + port);
});
```

If I only connect once, this is the stdout:

```
Listening on: 55671
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Received a connection from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

I've experimented with different orderings of the middleware and I had thought that this was working previously, but I may be remembering incorrectly.
Why is the next() call calling one middleware multiple times before moving to the other and then stopping?

Comment: Are you sure this just isn't all the static content coming down? Bear in mind that you are logging the IP *before* you serve any static content therefore you will get an output per static file served.

Comment: I'm serving quite a few files, so this makes sense. How could I change this to only log once? Should I be using a router rather than middleware?

Comment: it depends on what exactly you mean, this is working as expected, it's logging the IP *per request*. Are you asking is it possible to log the IP *per client* on first request?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm asking :)

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything out the box for this, however, one simple way of doing it is maintaining a list of active IPs (with the option of expiring them after X minutes) and checking this list before logging. See [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd4e173d93a508c853c9) for an example, it would be worth thinking about the expiration stuff though as scalability could become a problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the next() which calls thing several times. It just allow you to move forward otherwise your app is stuck after the first log statement.

However, the middleware order matters, here your logging middleware will be invoked for all the static files accessed.

It's good practice to put your static middleware before the logging one if you don't want to trace those.